# jstree killing live links

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Am implementing the jsTree plugin (http://www.jstree.com) on a project and it is generally working but it seems to prevent any links within the list that it is applied to from working. I have a Codepen example here:

http://codepen.io/WebDevCA/full/yinhk

If you go to Team A's Projects > Iteration 1 > Story A

then Story A should act as a link to Twitter (you can roll over the link to see that it points there). But jsTree keeps the link from working. Remove jsTree and the link works. Is there any way to convince jsTree to let it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is jstree uses the mouse click for a select event. If you want to do something else when the node is selected, then you'll need to bind to the select event:

```
    $("#tree").jstree(
      // options...
    ).bind("select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
      // your code here...
      // id of selected node will be: data.inst.get_selected()[0].id
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't even vote up an answer on my own question until I have a "reputation" of 15 or more.

Answer (score 1):

I have since implemented *one* possible solution using the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#selector A', function () {
  var goHere = $(this).attr("href");
  window.location.href = goHere;
});
```

The Codepen linked to above has been updated to show it working. http://codepen.io/WebDevCA/full/yinhk